# Disable button to prevent multiple submissions C# Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I'm using the validation class in .net to validate my form.

```
if (Validation.IsValid()){
            //do something if the form is valid
        }
```

I'm trying to disable the submit button by using javascript if it's valid.
How can I check if my form validation status in javascript/jquery?

**UPDATE**
I'm using System.Web.WebPages. Not System.Web.UI for my namespace

Comment: I think the answer from this question should do the trick.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543179/detect-if-asp-net-form-is-valid-with-javascript-jquery

I'd also recommend using a nonce to prevent multiple submissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if Asp.Net form is valid with javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543179/detect-if-asp-net-form-is-valid-with-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question, there is a javascript variable supplied by the webforms validation api:

`Page_IsValid`

so you can use something like

```
if(Page_IsValid)
{
    //Page already submitted logic.
}
```

For more info see: https://techbrij.com/client-side-validation-using-asp-net-validator-controls-from-javascript , which delves further into the api and is well worth a look.

Comment: It shows me error when i use Page_IsValid in my javascript/jquery